# How secure is a MD5 hash of an 128bit key

Tags: android, md5, entropy

Apparently, for the Android KeyChain an encrypted master key is stored along the MD5 hash of the **un**encrypted Key.
How secure is that?
MD5 is known to have collisions, but I guess we can assume with an input space limited to 128bit values no collisions turn up?
But still, given that there is no salt involved, isn't it possible for an powerful attacker to calculate rainbow tables and then instantly break every KeyChain an any Android device he gets his hands on?

Why is the plain MD5 hash of the secret key used to check if the Pincode is valid?

Comment: Do you have a link to whatever documentation you're referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collisions are not useful in this case.  You need a pre-image attack that can find the *correct* input that was used to generate the hash.  An alternate input that creates a collision is still not the correct key, and won't decrypt the data.  Finding the correct 128-bit random input is not feasible, even with MD5.

Comment: So this means to get any use out of this, I'd have to store all possible 128bit values and their MD5 values, which is impossible today?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed this needs some documents to speak clearly about the subject. Above the fold Google search resulted in http://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelorscripties/2013/Raoul_Estourgie___3022420___Analysis_of_Android_Authenticators.pdf page 30, which describes a pdk type functionality using a random salt. Assuming the research is valid, the usage of md5 in this equation would not be a weak link at all.